# How to connect two inputs in the same form

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I'm doing a form that have a multiple checklist, the user can select whatever they want and they neet to put a date, I already configured the checklist but, How can I connect the `input date` to the `input checkbox` because they need to be related to.

Soo my final result should be like:

```
results [{ 'Tramit1', 'date1' }, { 'Tramit2', 'date2' }];
```

Here's my current code of the part I'm talking about (because the form is bigger):

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> # </th>
            <th>Tràmit</th>
            <th>Validesa de l'autorització</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let permiso of permisos">
            <td id="first">
                <div class="form-check form-check-aj">
                    <label class="form-check-label">
                        <input (change)="onChange(permiso.nom, $event.target.checked)" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input">
                        <i class="input-helper"></i></label>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td id="first">{{permiso.nom}}</td>
            <td>
                <div id="datepicker-popup" class="input-group date datepicker">
                    <input type="date" id="datePicker{{permiso.id}}" name="bday" />
                    <span class="input-group-addon input-group-append border-left">
                        <span class="mdi mdi-calendar input-group-text"></span>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean they need to be related to?

Comment: You probably wan't a `formGroup`.

Comment: I think you may need a ngForm and ngModel to solve this